# Mongo upsert do not return modified object _id on update

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, upsert, mongotemplate

**Mongodb 4.2.15**

I'm tring to use mongo Updates with Aggregation Pipeline

My request is very big but here it's core structure

```
db.runCommand({
  "update": "collectionName",
  "updates": [
    {
      "q": { ... },
      "u": [
        {
          "$project": { ... },
          "$set": { ... },
          "$set": { ... },
          "$project": { ... }
        }
      ],
      "multi": false,
      "upsert": true
    }
  ]
});
```

After the first execute I receive a result with newly created object's **_id**

```
{
    "n" : 1,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "upserted" : [ 
        {
            "index" : 0,
            "_id" : ObjectId("619997f11501d6eb40c6f64a")
        }
    ],
    "opTime" : {
        "ts" : Timestamp(1637455857, 61),
        "t" : NumberLong(5)
    },
    "electionId" : ObjectId("7fffffff0000000000000005"),
    "ok" : 1.0,
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1637455857, 61),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : { "$binary" : "hA0tf5DXMqTNmnVXdMVnpnAKCU0=", "$type" : "00" },
            "keyId" : NumberLong(7018546168816730116)
        }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1637455857, 61)
}
```

After the second execution of the same request there is no modified object's **_id**

```
{
    "n" : 1,
    "nModified" : 1,
    "opTime" : {
        "ts" : Timestamp(1637456057, 19),
        "t" : NumberLong(5)
    },
    "electionId" : ObjectId("7fffffff0000000000000005"),
    "ok" : 1.0,
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1637456057, 19),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : { "$binary" : "U2yCP6nXUrjBN9ZiLanyl0rgxww=", "$type" : "00" },
            "keyId" : NumberLong(7018546168816730116)
        }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1637456057, 19)
}
```

The thing is that my filter conditions do not contain _id of the object but I need to return it with response. I see no useful request configurations. Any suggestions is it possible to get _id at response on update case?

Comment: you can do a find with the same creteria before the update, or if you want to be sure that you get exactly the ones that are updated maybe you can add a temp file, like update,find,update to remove that temp field, maybe there are better ways, but those might be ok for you case.  I don't think its possible to return all those ids, for example if you update 1million documents what to send back in 1 document?

Comment: Sounds like you want [findAndModify](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/#findandmodify) instead of update.

Comment: @Joe Thanks. You are right! `findAndModify` with a `"new": true` made a thing! The only point: I do not see there `"multi": false` configuration but since I'm updating data by unique index I guess for me this is okay.